# pyqt5 как сделать псевдокласс

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qss

Как сделать чтобы при наведении на self.wordButton изменялся цвет фона и тд.? Типа self.wordButton:hover{}

```
self.wordButton.setStyleSheet("""
                    font-size: 15px;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                    min-height: 40px;
                    max-height: 40px;
                    min-width: 100px;
                    max-width: 50px;
                    background-color: #ADD8E6;
                    border: 1px double #90EE90;
                """)
```

Comment: Цвет фона у кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вам задать цвет при событии `hover` при разном состоянии `pressed` ([подробнее](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states)):

- `QPushButton:hover:pressed`
- `QPushButton:hover:!pressed`

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

app = QApplication([])

pb = QPushButton('Click me!')
pb.setStyleSheet("""
QPushButton {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 50px;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    border: 1px double #90EE90;
}

QPushButton:hover:pressed {
    background-color: green;
}
QPushButton:hover:!pressed {
    background-color: yellow;
}

""")
pb.show()

app.exec()
```